# How to bind textblock to combobox with nested dictionary as source

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, data-binding, combobox

I have two `ComboBox`. The first one's source is a `dictionary`, with strings as keys, and objects as values. Upon selecting an item, the second `ComboBox` will be populated with keys from the selected item's separate `dictionary`. When an item from the second `ComboBox` is selected, the `TextBlock` should show the value of the key that was chosen in the second `ComboBox`. However, the textblock always appears empty. I have made sure the value does have actual data in it, which leads me to believe it's a binding issue.

Here's the relevant sections of my ViewModel:

```
GPHDTModel gphdtModel = new GPHDTModel();

private Dictionary<string, object> models = new Dictionary<string, object>();
public Dictionary<string, object> Models
{
    get
    {
        return models;
    }
}

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    gphdtModel.MessageID = "3";
    models.Add("GPHDT", gphdtModel);
}
```

Next here's the GPHDTModel:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public Dictionary<string, string> Fields
{
    get
    {
        return _fields;
    }
}

public GPHDTModel()
{
    _fields.Add("MessageID", MessageID);
}

private string _messageID;
public string MessageID
{
    get { return _messageID; }
    set { _messageID = value; OnPropertyChanged("MessageID"); }
}
```

Finally the view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ComboBox x:Name="NMEAlist"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Models,
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                               AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                          SelectedValuePath="Value" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="ModelList"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Value.Fields,
                                                ElementName=NMEAlist}"
                          SelectedValuePath="Value" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value,
                                          ElementName=ModelList}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Edit: Using a converter in the binding for the `TextBlock` to debug, it is showing the correct key, in this case "MessageID", but the value for the key is null, when it should be "3".

As @mm8 said below, when binding the textblock like this: `Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Key, ElementName=ModelList}"` "MessageID" appears in the textblock. So the binding is correct using `SelectedItem.Value`, but the value isn't being set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind to the `Value` property of the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=ModelList}" />
```

Comment: Tried this, still nothing unfortunately. I added a converter to the textblock so I could debug the value, and the value is showing as null. So it's not picking up the value for some reason.

Comment: Do you see the items in the ModelList ComboBox?

Comment: Yes. The first ComboBox is showing, GPHDT, and when I select that, the second one shows "MessageID". Upon selecting that though, the textblock stays empty instead of showing "3" which is what the MessageID property is equal to.

Comment: What does the TextBlock/converter say if you bind its Text property like this?: {Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ModelList}

Comment: Hmm, it's showing the value (which is the dictionary), and the key is "MessageID", but the value is null. Maybe my dictionary is messed up. Or my binding for the second combobox?

Comment: What if you bind to {Binding SelectedItem.Key, ElementName=ModelList}

Comment: Textblock still empty. The value in the converter shows "MessageID", which is the key.

Comment: So the TextBox and the converter don't show the same value? Try to get rid of the converter and simply bind to the SelectedItem.Key property as I suggested in my previous answer.

Comment: They do show the same value, it's just the fact that the "value" is null. So what's being passed into the converter is a key, value. With key being "MessageID", which is what I'm selecting in the combobox, and the value being null, when it should be "3".

Comment: Once again: If you bind to the *Key* property as I have suggested twice, you should see the value "MessageID" in the TextBox. If this works, you know that you haven't populated the Value property correctly.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes "MessageID" appears in the textblock. So it must be something wrong with the value property.

Comment: Yes. As far as the binding is concerned you could refer to my answer.